# isolateScope() gives undefined - Unit Testing directives with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ng-html2js

As stated in the title of the question, I am getting undefined when calling `isolateScope()`. I tried to Unit Test my Angular Directive based on the instructions given on [Unit Testing AngularJS Directives With External Templates](http://www.bluesphereinc.com/blog/unit-testing-angularjs-directives).

Here is my code:

**directive.js**

```
angular.module("myTestApp")
  .directive("testDirective", function(){
    return{
      restrict: "E",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope:{
        ngModel: "=",
        label: "@?"
      },
      templateUrl: "/mypath/templates/testDirective.html",
      link: function($scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl){
        $scope.functions = {},
        $scope.settings = {
          label: $scope.label ? $scope.label : ""
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

I have used `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` for templateUrl.

**karma.conf.js** (Code contains only the parts that are concerned with ng-html2js)

```
files:[
  //All Js files concerning directives are also included here...
  '/mypath/templates/*.html'
],

preprocessors: {
  '/mypath/templates/*.html': [ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  moduleName: 'template'
},

plugins: ['karma-*'],
```

**directiveSpec.js**

```
describe("testDirective Test", function(){
var scope, $compile,$httpBackend, template;

beforeEach(module('myTestApp'));
beforeEach(module('template'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}));

it("should check if the value of label attribute id set to dummyLabel", function(){
    $httpBackend.expect('GET','/mypath/templates/testDirective.html').respond();
    scope.label = 'dummyLabel';
    var element = angular.element('<test-directive label= "label" ></test-directive>');

    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    console.log(element);
    scope.$digest();
    console.log('Isolate scope: '+ element.isolateScope());
    expect(element.isolateScope().label).toEqual('dummyLabel');
});

});
```

Here the `console.log(element);` prints `{0: <test-directive label="label" class="ng-scope"></test-directive>, length: 1}`

**Problem:** `console.log('Isolate scope: '+ element.isolateScope());` gives `undefined`.

I looked on this problem on many questions in StackOverflow but was not able to find the correct solution.

Also, I have to use the `$httpBackend` to get the html file or else it throws `Unexpected Request` error.

I would be really grateful for any help since I am stuck on this error since past one week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who might have the same problem:

The directive testing do not work as expected when using the `$httpBackend` to mock the HTML files. It should be and it is possible to include HTML files by simply using the `ng-html2js` plugin. So I removed the $httpBackend calls and used `stripPrefix` to properly include my HTML files as modules. It worked!

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: So you did not use beforeEach(module('templates'))? You added the html file correct?  I am running into errors with this.

Comment: @stevek With `ng-html2js` plugin, you need not include the module in each test file. You can directly write it in your configuration file and it will be automatically be available in your test case. Please point me to your question on SO or provide me with more details.

Comment: Here is a link to my question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854470/setting-up-ng-htmljs-preprocessor-karma-preprocessor   .  I am stuck with getting back empty strings in my html files.  I am referencing the files as HTML in my karma.conf.js.  I am wondering if the the templateCached files also need to be directly referenced inside of the files array?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here at first glance but...

Your `.respond()` needs to return something.  Right now you are intercepting the request to your template and not responding with anything, thus resulting in empty data and `isolateScope()` being undefined.

Comment: Already tried by passing the content of `element` in the `.respond()` call. Did not work.