# setting up ng-htmljs-preprocessor karma preprocessor

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, ng-html2js

I am setting up my Karma configuration file, but I do not fully understand some of options that exist as I am not having success testing templates that have ran through the ngHtml2JsPreprocessor and have been

```
 $templateCached
```

Inside of the ngHtml2JsPreprocessor I can add a few key value properties involving paths.

```
 ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {

      stripPrefix: ".*/Went all the way back to the root of my application/",


     // moduleName: 'templatesCached'// 
    },
```

I commented out the templates for now to make sure that I am getting access to each file as module.  I am loading the modules with no error.  I can find the templateCached version in my dev tools.

```
beforeEach(module('template'));
```

My Templates folder sits outside the basepath I created.

```
basePath: 'Scripts/',
```

I have it referenced inside the  **preprocessors**  object

```
  preprocessors: {
    '../Templates/**/*.html' : ['ng-html2js']
},
```

Again all of my templates are now js files and cached.

I inside of my **package.json**   I saved the files as

```
save-dev

"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.2.2",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.2.1",
```

I referenced my installs in the plugins.

```
  plugins: [
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-sinon',
    'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
],
```

I have all of my files loaded

```
files: [

  //jquery libaries
  // angular libraries
  // Scripts files
  // source app.js
  // tests folder and files
]
```

My tests are running off of Karma start

However, my directive is just an empty string

```
  element.html()
```

returns ""

I have bard inject set up

```
bard.inject(
            "$compile",
            "$controller",
            "$rootScope",
            '$templateCache',
            "haConfig",
            "$q"
        );
```

Here is the inside of my beforeEach

```
 bard.mockService(haConfig, {
            getTemplateUrl: '/tst!'
        });

        //bard.mockService(haConfig, {});
        console.log('ha config2', haConfig.getTemplateUrl());

        var html = angular.element("<div explore-hero></div>");

        console.log('htl',haConfig.getTemplateUrl());

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        //templateCache
        element = $compile(html)(scope);
        //console.log(haConfig.getTemplateUrl(html));
        scope.$digest(element);
        console.log('missing text',haConfig.getTemplateUrl(html));

        controller = element.scope();

        console.log("element", element);
```

I have no idea why I am getting an empty string back.  I am creating the html file but, nothing is inside of it.

All I can wonder if I should have the  **the templatesCached files** showing up in a folder on my dev tools?  Also whether or not the files should be referenced inside of the files array inside  **karma.conf.js**

Right now I have the html files referenced?  I have tried the js files but that did not seem to do anything

Comment: Did you include the html files inside the `files:[]`? Also, try compiling the element in another `beforeEach` block.

Comment: I did.  I finally fixed this problem ended up being quite simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually quite simple fix.  I was tempted to delete it but, in case someone has a similar issue I want this to be available.

Inside the karma.conf.js I have a

```
   stripPrefix: 'rootDirectory'   // was already in place

   stripSuffix: '.js.html' // I had to make a strip on the templatesCached 

   prependSuffix: '.html'  // this is what I was searching for
```

When the preprocessor ran it templateCached all of my files.  However, they did not end the way that I was expecting them and I could not read them.  I had the module and other parts set up correctly.